# Apache 2.4 KeepAliveTimeout param has default value of 5ms or 5seconds?

Tags: apache2

I see in the document for apache 2.4, directive KeepAliveTimeout, the param unit is milisecond, but default value set to 5, is that means, default keepalivetimeout value is 5ms? isn't that too small compare to the old version?

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding the syntax in the doc. The syntax is a number followed by the optional literal 'ms'. Only if the 'ms' is there, the number is in milliseconds.

The default is 5 seconds.